# The type controllers.ReverseProducts cannot be resolved

Tags: playframework-2.0

When I am compiling my play application it is giving me the error:

> [error] E:\play\apps\warehouse\app\controllers\Products.java:56: `}' expected but eof found.

In Eclipse it gives an error:

> The type controllers.ReverseProducts cannot be resolved on the package name.

Comment: Post the `Products.java` code somewhere. Seems you have forgotten one `}`

Comment: @JulienLafont I have checked it at least a hundred times the } is balanced. when I delete this class and all it's reference it starts giving me compilation errors in all other classes that cannot find symbol controllers.ReverseProducts

Comment: Ok, but without code, we are not magicians ;)